# ¿Por qué datatable no crea ni actualiza registros? php no recibe respuesta de ajax, llevo días tratando de encontrar el error, soy nuevo en php

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

éste es mi código, ya verifiqué la respuesta de la consola desde ajax y php pero no me dicen nada, los inputs ya los verifique y los nombres están bien, me trae los datos necesarios para editar pero no actualiza ni crea, el código de crear es el mismo de editar, obvio con su respectiva linea de UPDATE -- SET -- WHERE

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#botonCrear").click(function(){
                $("#formulario")[0].reset();
                $(".modal-title").text("Agregar producto");
                $("#action").val("Agregar");
                $("#operacion").val("Agregar");
                $("#image").html("");
            });
 $(document).on('submit', '#formulario', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var tipo = $('#tipo').val();
            var description = $('#description').val();
            var detail = $('#detail').val();
            var amount = $('#amount').val();
            var price = $('#price').val();
            var coleccion = $('#coleccion').val();
            var image = $('#image').val();

        if(detail != '' && amount != '' && description != '')
               {
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"Agregar.php",
                        method:'POST',
                        data:new FormData(this),
                        contentType:false,
                        processData:false,
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            alert(data);
                            $('#formulario')[0].reset();
                            $('#modalUsuario').modal('hide');
                            dataTable.ajax.reload();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    alert("No hay suficiente información para guardar, algunos campos son obligatorios");
                }               
            });
```

y éste es el fragmento de código con el que lo llamo desde un archivo independiente de php, cabe recalcar que los archivos incluidos funcionan correctamente porque están mostrando mi datatable en orden, uno de ellos es una clase y el otro solo una funcion, el input operacion que entrega el valor es de tipo hidden

```php
require_once("Conexion.php");
include("funciones.php");

if ($_POST["operacion"] == "Agregar") {

        $stmt = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO productos(                     
                            tipo_producto,
                            descripcion_producto,
                            detalle_producto,
                            cantidad_producto,
                            precio_producto,
                            coleccion,
                            file_producto,
                            --estado
                            )
                     VALUES (
                            :tipo_producto,
                            :descripcion_producto,
                            :detalle_producto,
                            :cantidad_producto,
                            :precio_producto,
                            :coleccion,
                            :file_producto,
                          --  :estado
                            )");

        $resultado = $stmt->execute(
            array(
                        ':tipo_producto'    => $_POST["tipo"], 
                        ':descripcion_producto' => $_POST["description"],
                        ':detalle_producto' => $_POST["detail"],                          
                        ':cantidad_producto'    => $_POST["amount"],
                        ':precio_producto'  => $_POST["price"],
                        ':coleccion'    => $_POST["coleccion"],
                        ':file_producto'    => $_POST["image"],
                        //':estado' => $_POST['state']
                    )
                );

        if (!empty($resultado)) {
            echo 'Producto agregado exitosamente';
        }   

}
```

Comment: ¿Realmente tienes una columna llamada `--estado`?  Y si es así, ¿que pretendes poniendo esto `--  :estado` en los VALUES?  Lo pregunto por puro desconocimiento, nunca lo habia visto así. Quizás sí que es algo, como quizás es el error que buscas.

Comment: La columna estado la coloqué como posible solución pero tampoco funcionó,  por eso está comentada, para eso son los -- , asi se comenta en SQL, le he dado muchas vueltas y solo creo que el código JS no está enviando los valores suficientes porque no entra al if , se queda al ejecutar el datatable

Comment: Vaya, no sabia eso de los guiones, gracias por el aporte, pero entonces, ¿la coma que sigue a `file_producto,` tanto en la lista de columnas como en los VALUES es correcta?  ¿No da un error de sintaxis en alguna parte?  Por eso lo veia raro lo de los guiones.

Comment: Creo que tambien deberias poner el HTML del formulario para tener el poster completo de tu código, y para entenderlo mejor... veo que por una parte intentas capturar los datos con val() pero a la hora de la verdad no los usas, sino que usas el new FormData(this), y claro, no sabemos lo que es "this" pues no vemos el formulario completo y no sabemos si quizas no existe el name `operacion` con el valor Agregar que esperas capturar en PHP, etc